# Drag & drop file from the browser to desktop, change downloadURL preventing download

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to change the image that is being downloaded when an image is dragged from a browser into a folder. However, when I do this I get a file download blocked. Is there a way to resolve this?

```js
function imgChange(event){
event.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL','image/png:test.png:https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
}
```

```html
<img ondragstart="imgChange(event)" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4n_urpJ9XpwOTdzBVbGvactwHrPagYQrTJPYjxfxLGkSyu7nJZVqRVGAeohnPgKMrnKE&usqp=CAU">
```

Comment: it works fine for me. the file downloaded succesfully and i can open it.

Comment: That's strange, I'm receiving a "Download Blocked by your Organisation" error message. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: maybe you can read this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/downloads-being-blocked/eb4a38fe-bc9f-48b0-b36c-f7649ca4c605)